# Excel equals same value in corresponding column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have this table in `Excel`:

```
Column A      Column B    
master1       ID1                 
master2       ID1         
master3       ID2      
master3       ID2
```

I want to know for the Same `"ID"` in column B if they have the same `"Master"` `column A`.

```
Column A      Column B   different_master? 
master1       ID1                YES
master2       ID1                YES
master3       ID2                NO 
master3       ID2                NO
```

Which function I can use to do this?

Comment: You can use Pivot table to get the result.

Comment: you can try **IF+COUNTIFS**, use COUNTIFS to find out if there is duplicated master per ID and use IF to return YES or NO based on the count of duplicated master. Give it a go and if you encountered any problem you can update your question and someone if not me can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `Pivot Tables` to get the desired Result. Like in the below screenshot, 1 means they are different, more than 1 means not different.

[image]

---

**Pivot Table.**

[image]